# Detect if the value of keyCode equals an item in an array

Tags: javascript, char, keycode

I am building a small typewriter app and I have a problem with detecting whether a pressed button corresponds to the value of a span elements.

Basically, I have two divs, which contain spans with different letters for values.
I have the spans stored in a variable called leftPartSpans and rightPartSpans. So I basically try to run through each item with a loop and see if any of the chars in them correspond to the keyCode:

```
for (i=0; i<leftPartSpans.length; i++) {

            if(pressedKey == leftPartSpans[i].nodeValue) {

                leftPart.style.webkitTransform = "rotateZ(20deg)";

            }

        }
```

This, unfortunately, doesn't do the trick. You can see the entire project at http://codepen.io/gbnikolov/pen/wJHhk

Thanks in advance, 
Georgi

Answer (score 2):

`keydown` and `keyup` do not send different keycodes for upper and lower case letters. So your `pressedKey` is always going to be an uppercase letter while you use either one of those events. And since all your spans contain lowercase letters they will never match and your `if` block will never be triggered

You can use `keypress` which will send a different keycode for upper and lower case.

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  //...
});
```